# subscript operators of matrix for getting and assigning value

Tags: c++

I have a matrix of bool values

```
class BoolMatix
{

};
```

I would like to implement 2 subscript operators that can do this

```
BoolMatix b(...);
b[5]=true;
```

and

```
bool val=GetTruth(5);
```

`GetTruth(5)` will return `b[5]`

I have tried this

`const bool operator[](int index);`

but this seems to work with `GetTruth(index n)` only, how about the assignment ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a reference

```
bool& BoolMatrix::operator [](int index);
```

> const bool operator[](int index);

You return a const bool with this, so you just cannot assign something to it